# Clickable subtitle in html

Tags: html, subtitle

I'm trying to build a website using django where I want to host videos with subtitles.
My main goal is to make my subtitles **clickable** so whenever a user clicks or hovers on a word they can see the meaning of that word.
I'm currently using .vtt format for my subtitles.

Any ideas on how to do it?

below is the html code:

```html
<video id="example_video" class="" controls preload="none" width="640" height="264">
    <source src="{% static 'video/video.mp4' %}" type='video/mp4' />
    <track kind="captions" src="{% static 'captions.vtt' %}" srclang="en" label="English" />
</video>
```

this is also my subtitle :

```
WEBVTT

    00:03.000 --> 00:06.000
    trying to make each word a clickable element

    00:08.000 --> 00:09.225
    sample text
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### TL;DR

Off the top of my head; one way of going about doing it is to make a div for your subtitles area and the arrange everything in it using `flex` with `wrap` and `justify-center`. This div will contain `<a> ... </a>` tags for your words.

Then, you can dynamically fill up this template for each word in each timestamp.

### The template

Here's what I mean:

```css
.sub-word {
  /* padding: 0 5px; */
  padding-right: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.sub-word:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: green;
}

#sub-area {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="sub-area">
  <a href="link-to-definition-for-Trying" title="to attemp" class="sub-word">
        Trying
    </a>
  <a href="link-to-definition-for-to" title="preposition" class="sub-word">
        to
    </a>
  <a href="link-to-definition-for-make" title="to form" class="sub-word">
        make
    </a>
  <a href="link-to-definition-for-each" title="every" class="sub-word">
        each
    </a>
  <a href="link-to-definition-for-word" title="a meaningful of a laguage I guess" class="sub-word">
        word
    </a>
  <a href="link-to-definition-for-a" title="determiner" class="sub-word">
        a
    </a>
  <a href="link-to-definition-for-clickable" title="able to be clicked on" class="sub-word">
        clickable
    </a>
  <a href="link-to-definition-for-element." title="part of something" class="sub-word">
        element.
    </a>
</div>
```

If you hover on any word, it'll be highlighted and then a small pop-up will open with the definition in it. And if you click the words you can go to a dedicated page with a more comprehensive meaning and stuff you want.

### Backend and logic

You have different options for doing this as well. One idea is to compose something like a JSON file of subtitles in which they are separated by the timestamps and then the words and so on and so forth.

```json
{
  "00:00.000" : {
    "trying" : {
      "def": "attempting to",
      "link": "somewhere"
    },
    "to" : {
      "def": "preposition",
      "link": "somewhere"
    }
  },
  "00:03.000": {
    
  }
}
```

Which you can then dynamically change with JavaScript.

Edit: An example of generating HTML from subtitles:

Assuming your subtitles are always in the form of timestamps and strings, you can separate them and then put them into a dict with:

```py
for i in range(0, len(sub), 2):
    index = sub[i]
    words = sub[i+1]
    # making a dict as above
    sub_dict[index] = {word: define(word) for word in words.split()}
```

Then you can generate the tags with something like this:

```py
sub_div = '<div id="sub-area">'
for word in words.split():
    sub_div += f'<a href="{definition_link(word)}" title="{define(word)}" class="sub-word">{word}</a>'
sub_div += '</div>'
```

There definitely are libraries for doing this much cleaner as well.

Comment: Thanks alot, it gave me almost a view of what I should do. 
but in my case I will have a long subtitle.
so is there a way to write it dynamically?
for example it creates the element only in a specified timestamp